# I'm struggling with structs in c

Tags: c

I've been studying c for close to a year now for college and we just learned about structs right now I'm struggling with how to pass a struct elements (defined in main()) to other functions

```
void SwapScore(struct HighestScore ,struct HighestScore);

struct HighestScore
{
    char name[20];
    int Score;
};

int main()
{
    struct HighestScore Player;
    struct HighestScore CurrentPlayer;

    printf("Enter your first name");
    scanf("%s",&CurrentPlayer.name);
    Player.score = 1000000000;
    CurrentPlayer.score = 10;
    
    SwapScore(/* what should i insert here? */);
    return 0;
}

/* there is also an error in with the above declaration and this one */
void SwapScore(struct HighestScore *Player,struct HighestScore *CurrentPlayer)
{
    int temp = player.score; //I also can't access the struct for Player and CurrentPlayer
    player.score = CurrentPlayer;
    currentPlayer = temp;
}
```

I tried to swap both players scores and it didn't compile

Comment: In C variable names (and other identifiers) are case-sensitive. (There are a lot of other issues too, but let's start with the basics)

Comment: The function accepts `struct` pointers, and so the syntax should be `int temp = Player->Score; Player->Score = CurrentPlayer->Score; CurrentPlayer->Score = temp;` . The function should be called as `SwapScore(&Player, &CurrentPlayer);`

Comment: @bvghb218 _, Tip, save time.  Enable all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specify the prototype:

```
void SwapScore(struct HighestScore, struct HighestScore);
```

This says the function takes (copies of) two structures.

You implement:

```
void SwapScore(struct HighestScore *Player, struct HighestScore *CurrentPlayer)
```

This is a function that takes two pointers to structures.  It is not the same as the function you prototyped.

You probably need the prototype to read:

```
void SwapScore(struct HighestScore *player1, struct HighestScore *player2);
```

or thereabouts.

You'll also need to fix the implementation:

```
void SwapScore(struct HighestScore *Player, struct HighestScore *CurrentPlayer)
{
    int temp = Player->Score;
    Player->score = CurrentPlayer->Score;
    CurrentPlayer->Score = temp;
}
```

C is a case-sensitive language — you must be careful and consistent in your spelling.  Personally, I'd use all lower-case variable names.  The swap operation doesn't depend on what the two players represent, so I'd use neutral `player1` and `player2` as in the proposed prototype.  And I would be consistent in the member variable naming: either `name` and `score` or `Name` and `Score` but not the mixed capitalization you've used.  I'm a traditionalist; I'd use the lower-case member names.

As to how to call the function:

```
struct HighestScore Player = { "Edgar", 10 };
struct HighestScore CurrentPlayer = { "Esme", 20 };

SwapScore(&Player, &CurrentPlayer);
```